# HP laptop reboot BSOD code 0x00000124

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bsod

My laptop HP DV6 model 1103ee is getting rebooted after playing a video online or when using applications.

Example dump file:
 https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=24657CA7048734C3!114&authkey=!AIkt9HzuECtZc1Y

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 012213-45474-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 1/22/2013 7:54:39 PM
Bug Check String  : 
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000124
Parameter 1       : 0x00000000
Parameter 2       : 0x866bc1e4
Parameter 3       : 0xb614c000
Parameter 4       : 0x00000135
Caused By Driver  : halmacpi.dll
Caused By Address : halmacpi.dll+efcd
File Description  : Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntkrnlpa.exe+dee98
Stack Address 1   : halmacpi.dll+efcd
Stack Address 2   : ntkrnlpa.exe+d1a6c
Stack Address 3   : halmacpi.dll+f27f
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\012213-45474-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 143,152
==================================================
```

Comment: upload the dump (skydrive, dropbox) and add a link to your question.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=24657CA7048734C3!114&authkey=!AIkt9HzuECtZc1Y

Comment: I've already replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *AMD Turion(tm) X2 Ultra Dual-Core Mobile ZM-84* has a L1 Cache error:

```
WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: 85ebc024, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: b6000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 00000181, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------
Common Platform Error Record @ 85ebc024
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cde9520f47b488
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/3/2013 17:01:50 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 85ebc0a4
Section       @ 85ebc17c
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x86
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000200f31
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 85ebc0ec
Section       @ 85ebc23c
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : 31 0f 20 00 00 08 02 00 - 01 20 00 00 ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ 85ebc23c

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 85ebc134
Section       @ 85ebc2bc
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : ICACHEL1_SNOOP_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 1)

~MHz = REG_DWORD 2300
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ x86 Family 17 Model 3 Stepping 1
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ AMD Turion(tm) X2 Ultra Dual-Core Mobile ZM-84
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ AuthenticAMD
```

Check the CPU with Prime95 and make sure, the CPU is not overheating (check the temperature with speedfan or other tools). Clean the CPU cooler from dust.

*// Edit:*
Btw, this seams to be a common issue with your HP laptop:

http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/193415-random-bsods-stop-0x124.html

Comment: I found another way and it is working now i changed the power setting by reducing percentage of maximum  processor state in processor power management